# Как найти соединения типа T, L или + в массиве 3х3

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делая игру "3 в ряд" столкнулся в таким вопросом.
Мне нужно уничтожать подобные группы:

```
Буква T:          Буква L:          Знак +:
1 1 1             1 0 0             0 1 0
0 1 0             1 0 0             1 1 1
0 1 0             1 1 1             0 1 0
```

Где единички - это блоки одного цвета, а нули - какие-то другие. Причем эти буквы могут быть повернуты на 90, -90, 180 градусов.

На данный момент я смог сделать так, чтобы программа понимала, что определенная комбинация является такой буквой вот таким образом:

```
// Определяем, сколько точек есть на одной линии при определенном X и Y
// conn - это массив Vector2Int единичек
        Dictionary<int, int> dictX, dictY;
        dictX = dictY = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < conn.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!dictX.ContainsKey(conn[i].x))
                dictX.Add(conn[i].x, 1);
            else dictX[conn[i].x]++;

            if (!dictY.ContainsKey(conn[i].y))
                dictY.Add(conn[i].y, 1);
            else dictY[conn[i].y]++;
        }

        if (dictX.ContainsValue(3) && dictY.ContainsValue(3))
            return true;
        else return false;
```

Эта функция возвращает true, если смогла массив 3х3 содержит столбик из 3 единичек + строчку из 3 единичек.

Однако, помимо простого уничтожения я хочу добавлять специальный бонус, который при активации будет взрываться - это сейчас не так важно. Я хочу, чтобы этот бонус образовывался на пересечении этих строчки и столбца из 3 единичек.
То есть:

**2:**  `1`   `1`   `1`  
**1:**  `1`   `0`   `0`  
**0:**  `1`   `0`   `0`  
__**0** _**1** _**2**

**Бонус должен появляться в координатах (0,2) - на пересечении.**

Так вот, я не понимаю, как найти это самое пересечение intersection.
Чтобы не быть голословным и "без-собственных-идейным", могу сказать, что есть идея считать пересечением тот (X, Y), при котором

`(X,1) == 1 && (X, 2) == 1 && (X, 3) == 1... && (1, Y) == 1 && (2, y) == 1 && (3, Y) == 1...`

Но я не знаю, как точно это реализовать.
Добавлю, что на вход в указанную мной функцию я подаю List. Я заполнил его с помощью рекурсии. Он хранит позиции всех блоков того цвета, который был у блока, с которого я начал искать, которые соприкасаются с ним прямо или посредственно через те, которые соприкасаются прямо; те, которые соприкасаются с теми, что соприкасаются прямо и т.д.
Короче, для такого массива:

```
1 1 0 0
0 1 0 1
0 1 0 0
1 1 0 0
```

conn = { (0,0), (0,3), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (1,3) }, если начинать искать от левого нижнего угла.

**Update:** Массив conn не обязан быть 3х3. Он может быть, например, таким:

```
1 0 0 0
1 0 1 1
1 1 1 0
```

В таком случае ОПЯТЬ же должна удалиться буква L, чтобы мы получили:

```
* 0 0 0
* 0 1 1
* * * 0
```

Знаком * помечены те блоки, которые были удалены, так как составляют букву L.

Comment: Почему именно T и L? А крест а-ля "+"? Просто N в ряд не логичнее ли? Для каждой строки/столбца произвольной матрицы M x N определить есть ли в ней последовательность трёх (или более) единиц подряд. Такую задачу вы сможете решить? Встретили ноль - перешли к следующей клетке, встретили единицу - включили флаг "начинается серия единиц" (выключили если за ним ноль), параллельно считая количество единиц в серии. Достигли трёх в серии - ура, хорошая серия. Если у вас строго 3х3 матрица всегда - то можно просто захардкодить все необходимые матрицы с поворотами на 90 градусов чтобы сильно не думать.

Comment: Вот и я про тоже... А кроме Т и L в матрице 3x3 ,будут буквы?  Если нет, тогда точка с координаиами (1,1) "центр матрицы" однозначно определяет букву, как её не крути, т.е. (1,1) = 0 это L иначе это Т, теперь по алгоритму поиска пересечений создаём еще одну матрицу заполненую нулями, далее идем по строчкам заполняем эту матрицу пересечений.. прибавляя единицы там где последовательности более 3х по горизонтали, потом идем по вертикали прибавляя единицы там где последовательности более 3х но уже по вертикали, в итоге двойки в матрице пересечений говорят о пересечении в этой координате...

Comment: @AK я уже реализовал проверку линий. У меня их 4 вида: по 3, по 4, по 5, больше, чем по 5. Это *уже* есть. А про плюс вы правы, я про него забыл. Видимо потому, что игрок не может его собрать, он может собраться только сам при удачном совпадении падающих рандомных блоков.

Comment: @Akubik у меня есть этот самый массив с разными числами, но есть **ОДНА** цифра, насчет которой я проверяю. Буквы L, T и + я ищу ИМЕННО составленные из этой цифры. Других букв нет, так как есть ct возможные комбинации одинаковых блоков, при которых они исчезают - это: линия (из 3,4,5,>5 блоков) гориз. и вертик., буква L, буква T, крест (+). Это все. Почему я спрашиваю только про единички и нули в массиве? Потому что единичками я считаю все подходящие значения (те числа, которые равны тому ЧИСЛУ, из которого должны быть составлены буквы), а нулями - все поля матрицы, в которых этих чисел нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один из вариантов решения в лоб. Возможно, есть более изящные способы.

1. Пишем небольшое расширение, что бы проверять содержит ли наш `conn` искомый `Vector2Int`

```
static class ExtendOfVector2IntArray
{
    public static bool Contains(this Vector2Int[] array, Vector2Int value)
    {
        foreach (var currentVector in array)
        {
            if (currentVector == value)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        // optimize: преобразование данных в настоящую матрицу ускорит эту операцию
        return false;
    }
}
```

2. Делаем метод, что бы находить совпадения по горизонтали:

```
   private List<Vector2Int> GetRow(Vector2Int[] conn, Vector2Int startFrom)
    {
        List<Vector2Int> result = new List<Vector2Int>();

        const int maxPointer = 3; //количевство рядов
        int currentPointer = startFrom.x;
        for (int i = currentPointer+1; i < maxPointer; i++) //+1 что бы не добавлять себя же
        {
            if (conn.Contains(new Vector2Int(i, startFrom.y)))
            {
                result.Add(new Vector2Int(i, startFrom.y)); // todo: два одинаковых new не нужны
            }
            else
            {
                return result;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

3. Делаем аналогичный метод для вертикали

```
    private List<Vector2Int> GetСolumn(Vector2Int[] conn, Vector2Int startFrom)
    {
        List<Vector2Int> result = new List<Vector2Int>();

        const int maxPointer = 3; //количевство столбцов
        int currentPointer = startFrom.y;
        for (int i = currentPointer+1; i < maxPointer; i++)
        {
            if (conn.Contains(new Vector2Int(startFrom.x, i)))
            {
                result.Add(new Vector2Int(startFrom.x, i)); // todo: два одинаковых new не нужны
            }
            else
            {
                // или ещё проверить клетки сверху?
                return result;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

4. Делаем метод для запуска поиска фигуры для конкретной точки //conn - координаты клеток закрашенные одним цветом

```
   private Vector2Int[] findFigure(Vector2Int[] conn, Vector2Int checkIt)
    {
        bool isFigure = false;
        List<Vector2Int> result = new List<Vector2Int>();
        result.Add(checkIt);

        List<Vector2Int> row = GetRow(conn,checkIt);

        if (row.Count > 1) //3 в строке
        {
            isFigure = true;
        }

        result.AddRange(row);

        List<List<Vector2Int>> columns = new List<List<Vector2Int>>();

        foreach (var currentPointer in result)
        {
            columns.Add(GetСolumn(conn,currentPointer));
        }

        foreach (var currentColumn in columns)
        {
            if (currentColumn.Count > 1) // 3 в ряду
            {
                isFigure = true;
            }

            result.AddRange(currentColumn);
        }
        // todo: возможно нужна рекурсия для ловли совсем сложных фигур типа буквы Ш

        if (isFigure)
        {
            return result.ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            return null; //или не null, а (bool isFigure, Vector2Int[] coords) , что бы можно было вычеркнуть из поиска 
        }
    }
```

5. Делаем вспомогательный метод, что бы находить соседей конкретной точки:

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Возвращает соседей точки point в массиве figure
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="figure"></param>
    /// <param name="point"></param>
    private Vector2Int[] GetNeighbors(Vector2Int[] figure, Vector2Int point)
    {
        //todo: если мы точно знаем, что figure как-то отсортирован, то этим можно пользоваться
        List<Vector2Int> result = new List<Vector2Int>(4); //4 - максимальное кол-во соседей
        foreach (var currentPoint in figure)
        {
            if (currentPoint.x == point.x+1 && currentPoint.y == point.y) //сосед справа
            {
                result.Add(currentPoint);
            }
            if (currentPoint.x == point.x-1 && currentPoint.y == point.y) //сосед слева
            {
                result.Add(currentPoint);
            }
            if (currentPoint.x == point.x && currentPoint.y == point.y+1) //сосед сверху
            {
                result.Add(currentPoint);
            }
            if (currentPoint.x == point.x && currentPoint.y == point.y-1) //сосед снизу
            {
                result.Add(currentPoint);
            }
        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

6. Делаем метод, что бы находить пересечения в фигуре

```
    private Vector2Int[] GetСrossings(Vector2Int[] figure)
    {
        //todo: если фигура меньше 5 элементов сразу возвращаем пустышку        
        List<Vector2Int> result = new List<Vector2Int>();
        foreach (var currentPoint in figure)
        {
            var neighbors = GetNeighbors(figure, currentPoint);

            if (neighbors.Length > 2) // 3 или 4 соседа, по любому пересечение
            {
                result.Add(currentPoint);
                continue;
            }

            // если не интересны пересечения типа буквы Г, то continue при одном соседе
            bool oneRow = true; //все соседи на одной строке
            bool oneСolumn = true; //все соседи на одном столбце

            for (var i = 0; i < neighbors.Length-1; i++)
            {
                if (neighbors[i].x != neighbors[i + 1].x)
                {
                    oneRow = false;
                }

                if (neighbors[i].y != neighbors[i + 1].y)
                {
                    oneСolumn = false;
                }
            }

            if (!oneRow && !oneСolumn)
            {
                result.Add(currentPoint);
            }
        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

Немножко расширив метод сравнения можно научить эту штуку работать не только с бинарными массивами, но и с массивами int, что бы искать фигуры сразу на всем поле.

Comment: Благодарю, но возникло несколько вопросов, несмотря на то, что я реализовывал нахождение фигур чуть по-другому, ваш метод тоже мне понравился, однако вопрос все же был о том, как найти **пересечение** вертикальной и горизонтальной полос в в буквах T, L,  и + (о котором мне подсказали в первом комментарии). А, насколько я понял, ваш метод FindFigure просто возвращает массив позиций единичек, если фигура существует и null иначе.

Comment: Мне также кажется, вас смутило то, что в вопросе я приводил примеры на массиве 3x3, однако это не обязательно. Я подредактирую вопрос, явно указав это. Но я думаю это не большая проблема, ведь я смогу заменить `const int maxPointer = 3` на `const int maxPointer = ширина_conn`.

Comment: Добавил недостающую часть. Не тестировал, так-что возможны очепятки в коде, но основную идею я думаю поймете.  
PS: получилось как-то очень много вычислений, однозначно можно оптимизировать

Comment: Прочитал ваши дополнения к вопросу: отмечу, что мой алгоритм поиска фигур будет находить любые непрерывные фигуры, в которых есть ряд из 3 фигур, вкл. например букву Г. Кажется, у вас немножко другая задумка, но поиск пересечений всё равно должен работать как надо.

Comment: Для обращения к собеседнику используйте `@` - @МаксимФисман.

Comment: @aepot Насколько я знаю, человеку задавшему вопрос всегда приходят уведомления обо всех дейтсвиях на нем. Человеку, давшему ответ, - действия на ответе

Comment: @МаксимФисман уведомления автоматом приходят только автору поста, под которым комментарий.

Answer (score 4):

Описывать каждый возможный вариант, как отдельный это сложно и бессмысленно.

Находишь все линии 3+! Это довольно просто прочесав весь массив по горизонтали и вертикали. Найденные группы записываешь в объекты `Figure`.

У нас получится `List<Figure> Figures`, которые могут пересекаться. Сравниваем каждый с каждым и если они пересекаются, записываем новую фигуру из двух в массив `List<Figure> CombineFigures` и оставляем на эту новую фигуру ссылку (`Contains`) в тех из кого она была сделана.

```
public enum TileType { Red, Green, Blue };

public class Figure {
    public TileType Type;
    public List<Vector2Int> Tiles;
    public Figure Contains;

    public Figure (TileType type) {
        Type = type;
    }

    public Figure (Figure figureA, Figure figureB) {
        Type = figureA.Type;
        Tiles.AddRange(figureA.Tiles);
        Tiles.AddRange(figureB.Tiles);
        Tiles = Tiles.Distinct();
        figureA.Contains = this;
        figureB.Contains = this;
    }

    public void Add (Figure figure) {
        Tiles.AddRange(figure.Tiles);
        Tiles = Tiles.Distinct();
        figure.Contains = this;
    }

    public bool Cross (Figure figure) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Tiles.Count; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < figure.Tiles.Count; j++)
                if (Tiles[i] == figure.Tiles[j])
                    return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < Figures.Count-1; i++)
    for (int j = i+1; j < Figures.Count; j++)
        if (Figures[i].Type == Figures[j].Type && Figures[i].Cross(Figures[j]))
            if (Figures[i].Contains == null && Figures[j].Contains == null)
                CombineFigures.Add(new Figure(Figures[i], Figures[j]));
            else if (Figures[i].Contains != Figures[j].Contains) {
                if (Figures[i].Contains != null)
                    Figures[i].Contains.Add(Figures[j]);
                else
                    Figures[j].Contains.Add(Figures[i]);
            }
```

В итоге результатом будут все `CombineFigures` и все `Figures` не имеющие комбинаций (`Contains == null`).

И все сработает на любой комбинации, хоть такой

```
X X X . .
. X . . .
X X X X X
. X . . .
```

Comment: Спасибо. А что не так с Distinct? Почему он выдает `List<Vector2Int>  не содержит определения Distinct(), и не удалось найти...`

Comment: `using System.Linq;`